# angularjs events for launching modals

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to launch modal windows from different parts of my angular application for viewing or editing content without changing states/url.

My current approach is to create a module for each modal and in the run() method, add a $rootScope.$on listener. I can then $emit from anywhere in the app and pass a callback function for when the modal has finished doing it's thing for the item that $emitted to update itself if necessary. I understand I could also use promises instead of callbacks.

I am not so much concerned with callbacks/promises but more the fact that I am using $scope and $rootScope to dispatch and listen for events. Is there a better way of doing this such as having some sort of central event dispatching service, or is this just re-inventing what already exists in $rootScope?

Can anyone provide examples of a good approach?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386959/angularjs-events-for-launching-modals

Comment: I've deleted the other one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleaner way is to emit events, you can do it using a service to abstract this behavior, this service will do 3 things:

- `$emit` the event
- add a `$q.defer()` on the $emit
- return a `defer.promise` to the caller

That way is transparent for the caller but the listener of the event must `resolve` or `reject` the event with the corresponding `result` or `reason`

**Update**

[**Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ycb8wX?p=preview) is a working example, using an `eventEmitter` service, and a `eventListener` modules, but probably should be more modular this separation, otherwise you will end up with a single module which handles all the listener for the entire application

Comment: thanks for your reply, do you have an example or a link to an example?

Comment: I just updated the answer with an example, i hope this solves your doubt